# Core plot adding data in from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, core-plot

Lets say I have two NSMutableArrays, one has a 1,2,3,4 and is called x and one has 200, 500,120, 400 and is called y. I have a graph made, I just cant seem to figure out how to add the data from the NSMutableArray. I am guessing I will use a for loop, is thios correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a datasource to feed data to a Core Plot plot. There are many example apps included with Core Plot. The *Plot Gallery* app demonstrates all of the available plot types and is a good place to start.

Comment: ok, dis helpes but how do you do ir from an already created nsmutablearray?

Comment: Just read the numbers from your array in the datasource. Return the `count` of the array from `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:`. In `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`, use the `field` to decide whether to return the x- or y-value and use the `index` as the array index.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @ugg lesio i have prepared a `simple example to show/draw charts in ios`. you can [download it here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/ChartView) which would help you to draw with your data.